# Export menu as feature?

Tags: 7, navigation, features

How can I export a menu as a feature? I found the [menu import](http://drupal.org/project/menu_import) module, but it does not work with this feature.

Comment: To clarify: I want to do this via drush, rather than the UI.

Comment: And I'm using Drupal 7 with the most recent, stable modules.

Comment: FYI.. The http://drupal.org/project/menu_import module added drush integration since 1.2.